# Create dataframe from percentile of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to make a dataframe using the the 25th, 50th and 75th percentile of another dataframe. This dataframe captures a value every hour for a couple of years. And I want to make a dataframe where my hours are the index. And the columns are labeled: '25%', '50%', '75%'.
From the dataframe I have I can already get the hour. How would I go about this?

To be clear, there are multiple measurements per hour (because it's in another year or another day, week or even month). And I want to take the 25, 50th and 75th percentile of these and make a dataframe out of it.

All help is apreciated!

Comment: Can you please share a sample of how your input dataframe looks and also how your desired dataframe looks?

Comment: https://imgur.com/Omg7Nl1 Here is an example (head) and here the desired https://imgur.com/PMY2lvj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, `df` is the dataframe with columns `hour` and `value`. You can collect values for each percentile into dictionary and then create a new dataframe from it:

```
feed_dict = dict()
for perc in 25, 50, 75:
    feed_dict[f"{perc}_percentile"] = df.groupby("hour")["value"]\
        .apply(lambda x: np.percentile(x.dropna(), perc))
    
pd.DataFrame(feed_dict)
```

Comment: When I do this, I get NaN. My data is called df_nonlockdown. Which means this should work right? :
`data = dict()
for perc in 25, 50, 75:
    data[f"{perc}%"] = df_nonlockdown.groupby('hour')['FN']\
        .apply(lambda x: np.percentile(x, perc))
    
pd.DataFrame(data)`

Comment: This means, that you have missing values. I've fixed the code with `x.dropna()`

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed what I was looking for